# How to change speed of dc motor using potentiometer?

Tags: voltage-regulator, dc-motor, potentiometer, fan

I want to change the speed of a DC motor(12V,2000RPM) using a pot and operate a table fan(where I've replaced its AC motor with DC).Now the problem is I get a regulated output at o/p of 7812 but not after connecting the pot(10k)!
Need ua help guys!
Thanks!

Comment: Maybe an LM317 will work for you.

Answer (score 2):

[LM317](https://www.fairchildsemi.com/datasheets/LM/LM317T.pdf):

[image]

To use your 10K pot you can use it for R2 and change R1 to 1.2K ohms. It will not work correctly without the fan connected because the load current will be too low for the LM317 to regulate.

Adjustment range (with fan connected) should be 1.25 to around 12V, assuming at least 14V in. Check it doesn't get too hot- you might have to add a heatsink or bolt it to something- at least you have a fan to cool it.

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to do a whole lot with just a potentiometer.

But you can build an adjustable regulator that has it's output voltage controlled by the potentiometer, or you can use a small PWM DC drive that uses the pot as a reference.

The point is, you will need to use the pot to control another device that can generate a 0 to 12VDC output to the motor.

Comment: Mm-hmm..Ill try using LM317!Hope it'll work :)